# Magento 2 cron not working

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

```
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/magento-2/bin/magento cron:run
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/magento-2/update/cron.php
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/magento-2/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

this is cron job setting and my crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
  <group id="default">
    <job name="send_call" instance="Custom\Module\Model\Observer\Event" method="sendEmail">
      <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
  </group>
</config>
```

I check many times but cron not working

Comment: and error message?

Comment: Nothing error but i write a log inside sendEmail function
but when i find log is empty

Comment: The method you have specified is senMail. Is that correct? Should it sendMail?

Comment: i wrote wrong here but in code that is write so please give accurate answer

Comment: 1. Did you try to run `php /var/www/magento-2/bin/magento setup:cron:run` manually? 2. Where is your crontab.xml located?

Comment: Sorry, above I meant `php /var/www/magento-2/bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: do you have any entry in the `cron_schedule` table?

Answer (score 11):

Flush Cache and Run Cron again.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: This worked for me, for the scenario I had. But I am not sure if this is recommended approach.

Answer (score 6):

If flushing the cache with `php bin/magento cache:flush` doesn’t work for you, check the `cron_schedule` table and look for your Job Code there. Chances are one of the instances is stuck with status "running" due to some error in your observer. If so, just delete that line from the cron_schedule table and try running the cron again.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue in my case. There were few cronjobs whose name have been renamed in the module and hence they were failing with the message "No Callback Found"

Comment: I have same error message "No callbacks found", I have checked my cronjob name in module, it is the same name everytime, still having this error message. Do you have any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: @RonakParmar Check your <job> tag in the xml file of the crontab. Both, "instance" and "method" properties must be specified and must be valid.  The "instance" property must point to the file where the function to be executed exists and the "method" property must be the name of the function to be executed within that file.

Comment: @DanielKratohvil Thanks for assist. I have fixed my issue. I have used crontab.xml of Magento core module, and done required changes as per my custom module. Now my cron job is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks !! this works for me

Comment: Thank you! Only this answer helped me!!

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to **restart your cron service** in Host Server

Commands for RHEL/Fedora/CentOS/Scientific Linux user

If you are using Redhat (RHEL)/Fedora/CentOS Linux use the following commands.

**Task: Start cron service**

To start the cron service, use:

```
# /etc/init.d/crond start
```

OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user:

```
# service crond start
```

OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user:

```
# systemctl start crond.service
```

**Task: Stop cron service**

To stop the cron service, use:

```
# /etc/init.d/crond stop
```

OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user:

```
# service crond stop
```

OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user:

```
# systemctl stop crond.service
```

**Task: Restart cron service**

To restart the cron service, use:

```
# /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user:

```
# service crond restart
```

OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user:

```
# systemctl restart crond.service
```

Answer (score 1):

The group with id "default" works with a period of every 15 minutes.
Try to replace it with the "index":

```
...
 <group id="index">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "which php" command to see the exact php path running on the server. Use that php path to configure by the SSH user used for the magento not by the root user.

Go to Magento installation and run

crontab -e

```
* * * * * path_to_php var/www/html/***.com/v2/bin/magento cron:run
* * * * * path_to_php var/www/html/***.com/v2/update/cron.php
* * * * * path_to_php var/www/html/***.com/v2/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```